# 3.41GB truecrypt file not syncing on ubuntu one

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, truecrypt

I am unable to sync a 3.41GB  ***.tc*** (*truecrypt*) file using Ubuntu One. It keeps saying `0% used`,  `0bytes of 5GiB` and `File Sync is up-to-date`

How do I sync this file to Ubuntu-One?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really bad idea. If you got this working, you would have to upload the **entire 3.41 .tc file** [every time you made any changes](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+question/74734) within it.

For a better option, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75377/encrypting-data-in-ubuntu-one) here on Ask Ubuntu. Skip my answer posted there, and scroll down to @jadahl's answer for a better way to make this work.